Speech recognition save speech to wav too faster
When I run this script on my computer, the library records the voice at normal speed. When I do it on OrangePI Zero 3, it records the voice at 1.5-2 times the normal speed.
The only difference between running on my computer and on OrangePI is the device index. On my computer I don't specify it, but on OPI it is not automatically detected.
import wave
import queue
import vosk
import sys
import json
import speech_recognition
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


def record_and_recognize_audio(*args: tuple):
    with microphone:
        recognized_data = ""

        try:
            #print("Listening...")
            audio = recognizer.listen(microphone, 5, 5)

            with open("input.wav", "wb") as file:
                file.write(audio.get_wav_data())

        except speech_recognition.WaitTimeoutError:
            print("Can you check if your microphone is on, please?")
            return ""

        wf = wave.open("input.wav", "rb")
        results = ""

        while True:
            data = wf.readframes(4000)
            if len(data) == 0:
                break
            if rec.AcceptWaveform(data):
                recognizerResult = rec.Result()
                results = results + recognizerResult

        wf.close()
        os.remove("input.wav")

        results = results + rec.FinalResult()
        recognized_data = json.loads(results)["text"]

        return recognized_data
    

mic_blocked = False

def block_mic():
    global mic_blocked
    mic_blocked = True

# ------------------- vosk ------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = queue.Queue()


    def callback(indata, frames, time, status):
        """This is called (from a separate thread) for each audio block."""
        if status:
            print(status, file=sys.stderr)
        if not mic_blocked:
            q.put(bytes(indata))

    load_dotenv()

    recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
    microphone = speech_recognition.Microphone(sample_rate=44100, device_index=2)

    model = vosk.Model("model")
    rec = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, 44100)
    rec.SetWords(True)

    with microphone:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(microphone, duration=2)

    try:
        while True:
            voice_input_str = record_and_recognize_audio()

            if voice_input_str != "":
                print(voice_input_str)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nDone')
        # write_message("     Jarvis         disabled")
    except Exception as e:
        print(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e))


Console write ALSA errors every time, but it worked correctly
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1369:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.0.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory


Is there a specific question here?

Are you using the same microphone on both your computer and the Orange Pi? And are you using bluetooth or USB for the microphone? Could you please also do print(vars(microphone)) after microphone = speech_recognition.Microphone(sample_rate=44100, device_index=2) in your code so we can compare the Microphone objects between the two operating systems.
I suspect that a default configuration on the Orange Pi is causing the microphone to record at a different sample_rate, even though it's explicitly given, e.g. if Orange Pi is recording in mono and your computer is recording in stereo.
